# Magento 2.2.5: How Cms Page Search Work?

Tags: magento2, cms, search, magento-2.2.5

Like i said in the title, i dont know how the Search in Catalog work.

As far as i know, the Search is render through this code in this ui-component:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\vendor\magento\module-cms\view\adminhtml\ui_component\cms_page_listing.xml

<filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
```

And when i copy this code and paste to my ui-component, it doesn't work at all, i can render the search text box, but when i write something and push "Enter", nothing happened.

[image]

EDIT 1:

(Here is my ui-component, InstallSchema and UpgradeSchema file)

File : C:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\Aht\BannerSlider\view\adminhtml\ui_component\banner_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">banner_form.banner_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="save_and_continue" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveAndContinueButton"/>
            <button name="save" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\SaveButton"/>
            <button name="reset" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\ResetButton"/>
            <button name="delete" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\DeleteButton"/>
            <button name="back" class="Aht\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\BackButton"/>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>banner_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>banner_form.banner_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="banner_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="banner/manage/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Aht\BannerSlider\Model\Banner\DataProvider" name="banner_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label/>
        </settings>
        <field name="id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataScope>id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
        <field name="name" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">banner</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Banner Name</label>
                <dataScope>name</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

File: InstallSchema.php

```
class InstallSchema implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface
{

public function install(\Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface $setup, \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();
    if (!$installer->tableExists('banner')) {
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('banner')
        )
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                ],
                'ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable => false'],
                'Name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                'Created At'
            )->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                'Updated At')
            ->setComment('Banner Table');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }

    if (!$installer->tableExists('slide')) {
        $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
            $installer->getTable('slide')
        )
            ->addColumn(
                'id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                null,
                [
                    'identity' => true,
                    'nullable' => false,
                    'primary'  => true,
                    'unsigned' => true,
                ],
                'ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'banner_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'Banner Id'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'name',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                ['nullable => false'],
                'Name'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'url',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'URL'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'image',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                255,
                [],
                'Image'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'created_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                'Created At'
            )->addColumn(
                'updated_at',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                null,
                ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                'Updated At')
            ->setComment('Slide Table');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

File: UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Aht\BannerSlider\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade( SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context ) {
        $installer = $setup;

    $installer->startSetup();

    if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {

        if (!$installer->tableExists('banner_slide')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('banner_slide')
            )
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary'  => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'banner_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable => false'],
                    'Banner ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'slide_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable => false'],
                    'Slide ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                    'Created At'
                )->addColumn(
                    'updated_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Updated At')
                ->setComment('Banner Slide Table');

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        if (!$installer->tableExists('banner_page')) {
            $table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
                $installer->getTable('banner_page')
            )
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary'  => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'banner_id',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                    null,
                    ['nullable => false'],
                    'Banner ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'page_url',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    255,
                    ['nullable => false'],
                    'Page Url'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT],
                    'Created At'
                )->addColumn(
                    'updated_at',
                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                    null,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Updated At')
                ->setComment('Banner Page Table');

            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        }

        if ($installer->tableExists('slide')){
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('slide');
            $columnName = 'banner_id';
            if($connection->tableColumnExists($tableName,$columnName, $schemaName = null)){
                $connection->dropColumn($tableName, $columnName, $schemaName = null);
            }
        }
    }

    $installer->endSetup();
}
}
```

EDIT 2 (fixed in EDIT 3):

I'm following Marius solution.

But it doesn't seem to work. It throw an error when i'm trying "php bin/magento setup:upgrade"

Installing schema... Upgrading schema... SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.banner_name' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE BANNER_NAME

So here is what i update to UpdateSchema.php.

```
if ($installer->tableExists('banner')){
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
            $connection->addIndex(
                    $setup->getIdxName(
                        $installer->getTable('banner'),
                        ['name'],
                        AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                    ),
                    ['name'],
                    ['type' => AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
                );
        }
```

EDIT 3:

So i was trying Marius solution like this (the difference is i give it a table in "addIndex" function):

```
if ($installer->tableExists('banner')){
            $connection = $installer->getConnection();
            $connection->addIndex(
                $installer->getTable('banner'),
                $setup->getIdxName(
                    $installer->getTable('banner'),
                    ['name'],
                    AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
                ),
                ['name'],
                AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
            );
        }
```

Also, before i do that, i have to clear cache and delete my module in "setup_module" table, `and it work`. But for some reason, when i click "x" to clear the search, it throw 2 column exactly like the same( look the image below):
[image]

1 more problem is i cant search with "c". I've read some where that "fulltext_search" cant be use with 5 or less character. So there are any solution to fix this?

Comment: In which module it's not working?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i'm trying to do the search, so the one is not working is my module.
I'll edit the post so you can see my ui-component. :)

Comment: Edited, please check :D

Comment: can you post your `InstallSchema.php` file in here ?

Comment: Ok, hold on, i'm editing

Comment: Edited, please check :)

Comment: I've updated the post, please check :)

Comment: I don't have another solution to your problem, but since your search box should search only in the `name` field it is kind of useless. you can always use the filter input for the name and get the same result.

Comment: yes thanks you, i'm learning magento, so i'm trying to do all of it, maybe next time i will find the way to remove " filter by name ".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general search field in the grid works with full text search indexes. Your table does not have any, that's why nothing happens.
You need to add to your table a full text index that indexes all the fields you want searched.
Here is an example from the [cms module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.2-develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/Setup/InstallSchema.php#L76)

```
->addIndex(
        $setup->getIdxName(
            $installer->getTable('cms_block'),
            ['title', 'identifier', 'content'],
            AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT
        ),
        ['title', 'identifier', 'content'],
        ['type' => AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_FULLTEXT]
);
```

This means that you are creating a full text index on the fields `title`, `identifier` and `content` for the cms block entity.

Comment: well , I'm trying to follow your code, but it return an error " Installing schema... Upgrading schema... SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento.banner_name' doesn't exist, query was: DESCRIBE `BANNER_NAME` "

Comment: I was replaced "cms_block" with "banner" and " 'title', 'identifier', 'content' " with "name". That's all.

Comment: I've updated the code, please check

Comment: I have no idea where that `banner_name` comes from.

Comment: hmmm .. This is weird @@
incase you wanna know the code, i've update the UpgradeSchema.php in my post.

Comment: hmm, i was trying to clear cache and also delete my module in "setup_module" table in mysql, and it work, but for some reason, it can only find my banner_name = "banner_1", but not my banner_name = "c5" .

Comment: and also, when i click "x" to delete search text and get back to list banner, but it render 4 result with banner_name = "banner_1" for me.

Comment: I've updated the post, please check :)